# Sending custom event form one page to another

Tags: c#, xaml, events, uwp

I am making an **UWP desktop** application with **C#** & **Xaml** it is banking application for school project and I am struggling with payment history logic.

I want from user to enter some price into the text box which is on **Page1** , than he will press the button, after that the app will navigate to the main screen.
If the payment was successful (this logic is already in my app and you don't have to focuse on that) in the **Page2** the text block will be created (but the user won't be able to see it unless he opens the **Page2**)

**Page 1.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBox x:Name="Money" Height="100" Header="Enter your money"/>
        <Button
                x:Name="MyBtn"
                Click="Button_Click"
                Content="Ok"
                Margin="30"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Page 1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public delegate void PaymentEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);

    public event PaymentEventHandler SuccessfullPayment;

    protected virtual void OnSuccessfullPayment()
    {
        if (SuccessfullPayment != null)
        {
            SuccessfullPayment(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //in case that payment is successful (this logic is unnecesary in this example)

        OnSuccessfullPayment();
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainBankPage)); 
    }


}
```

**Page 2.xaml**

```
<Grid>  
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel x:Name="RootLayout" Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**Page 2.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
{
    public Page2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    
    public void Initialization()
    {
        var payment= new Page1();
        payment.SuccessfullPayment += CreateTextBlock;
    }

    public void CreateTextBlock(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textblock = new TextBlock();
        textblock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 15, 0);
        textblock.Width = 400;
        textblock.Height = 60;
        textblock.FontSize = 20;
        textblock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        textblock.Text = "Payment was successfull";
        RootLayout.Children.Add(textblock);
    }
    
    
}
```

**Main page**

*There are only 6 buttons which user can interact with to navigate between pages in my app so I think it is unnecessary to show code*

I was trying to do it through custom events (it is shown in the example), but it didn't work.

I am kinda new in app development so if this is stupid way to do it I am open for other options

Note: my app is much more complex I just want to know how to do this specific thing so I have created this simple example :)

Hope everything is clear to you if not comment and I will try to improve the question as much as I can.

Thank you so much for your time and answers.

Comment: What do you want to implement indeed? What's the expected behavior? Passing data from Page1 to Page2?

Comment: So for example user will "make a valid payment (5 €)" than he could do whatever he wants in the app. But behind the scene, in the **page2** text block will be crated which text would be "payment successful" but user will see it only if he will navigate to that page. Hope you understand now :) If not just let me know

Comment: Based on your description, @mm8 's solution should be able to do that. Or take it a step further, you could create a singleton to pass your parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no point of raising an event if no one has registered to handle it. If I understand your issue correctly, there is no `Page2` created by the time you raise the event from `Page1` so this won't work.

Instead of raising an event, you could store the information in some global object that can be accessed from anywhere in the application whenever.

You could for example create a static class:

```
public static class AppInfo
{
    public static string SharedInfo { get; set; }
}
```

...and get and set properties of it from any page, e.g.:

**Page1**:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //in case that payment is successful (this logic is unnecesary in this example)
    AppInfo.SharedInfo = "Payment was successfull";
    OnSuccessfullPayment();
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainBankPage)); 
}
```

**Page2**:

```
public void Initialization()
{
    var textblock = new TextBlock();
    textblock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 15, 0);
    textblock.Width = 400;
    textblock.Height = 60;
    textblock.FontSize = 20;
    textblock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    textblock.Text = AppInfo.SharedInfo;
    RootLayout.Children.Add(textblock);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for not making myself clear. 
'Page 2' is already crated and user can do payment any time in 'Page 1'. And the app has to crate new text block every time in Page 2. And on the 'Page 2' can be as many text blocks as user's successful payments. It is similar to the payment history in real bank apps. And also my app is much more bigger than this, this is just "simple example" because I don't know how to make that payment history think. Hope you will help me  Have a great night :)

Comment: How is it already created? Are/How you displaying more than one page at once?

Comment: It is created as I have mentioned there is page named MainPage, here can user go to another pages of my app and from MainPage user can go either to Page1 or Page2.

And there I want to crate text box depending on either the Payment was successful or not.

Comment: @wpsimon09 Generally, a Page object will not be created unless when the user navigated to it. When you call `typeof(Page)` when navigation, Page2 will be created. I agree with @mm8, there is no need for a custom event.  @mm8 's solution about saving the information into a global object should still work for your scenario.

Comment: Oke thank you, I 'll try to make use of it :)